# Is it possible to assign variables a value in a lambda function?

Tags: python, function, lambda

How can I assign a variable inside a lambda expression?

So for example I have lambda function like this.

```
o = lambda x,y: x+y
```

I want x+y to equal another variable so I can use it later in the lambda expression.

```
o= lambda x,y: avg = x+y #this thorws an error
```

I tried reading up on lambda documentation but nothing helps.

If I can make a variable, how would I use it later?

Comment: No. Lambdas must evaluate to an _expression_. You cannot include any statements, such as assignments. If you need use a statement, create a local function.

Comment: @Brian okay thanks for the info thats what i thought

Comment: You can use the returned value. `avg=o(1,2)`.

Comment: What do you mean with "use it later in the lambda expression"?

Comment: @HeapOverflow I meant if avg=x+y then I could do avg*5 later in the expression so I don't have to type out x+y over and over every time I want to do something with them. But if I can't assign them a variable to x+y then i'd have to type x+y every single time.

Comment: If you showed an actual example with that usage, people might be willing to show how to make it work.

Comment: it's possible with Python 3.8 assignment expressions.

Comment: As an aside, you *should not be assigning lambdas to names*. That defeats *their only advantage*, which is to by anonymous. If you are going to do that, just use a full function definition

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, with the new `:=` "walrus" assignment operator, you can make assignments in an expression, including in lambdas. Note that this is a new feature requiring Python 3.8 or later.

```
lambda x, y: (avg:=x+y)
```

There are ways to simulate this operator on older versions of Python as well, but `:=` is the proper way to do it now.

Comment: The proper way to "simulate" it before was to just use a regular function definition :)

Comment: I tried this. `avg=0;a=lambda x,y:(avg:=x+y);print(avg)` still prints `0`.

Comment: @Ch3steR You never called the lambda, so why did you expect the assignment to happen?

Comment: It was a typo I called `a(1,2);print(avg)`.

Comment: Check this link : https://repl.it/repls/ZealousWanCygwin

Comment: @Ch3steR the `avg` is scoped inside the lambda, same as a normal assignment in a function definition. Maybe you were expecting a nonlocal? You can't do nonlocal assignments in lambdas. If you put the print inside the lambda, it would work.

Comment: @gilch Yeah, got your point.